# Big problem with Genetic Algorithm and Support Vector Regression

Tags: r, forecasting, svm

I am working on a forecasting function that optimize hyperparameters of a nu-SVR with RBF kernel using a genetic algorithm. The model includes lagged values of the dependent variable and lagged values of other regressors.

SOME EXPLANATIONS OF WHAT I DO

The criterion used for fitness by the GA is minus the mean squared error out-of-sample. The OOS errors are generated using an expanding window forecast exercise. If you leave out 30% of a 100 observations training set, the GA will estimate X many SVRs with hyperparameters it chooses on observations from 1 up to (70-h+1) where h is the forecast horizon. It then will forecast observation 70 for all hyperparameter values considered and compute the error. Then, the window is expanded to included observation (71-h+1) and thep rocess is repeated. All hyperparameters considered by the GA in one generation will have generated 30 OOS forecasting errors. The fitness for each hyperparameter vector is -mean(errors^2).

I produce subsamples for the expanding window exercise using a custom function that outputs a list of lists. In the example above, we would have 30 items in the list. In each case, [[1]] would be the subsample used for estimation and [[2]] contains the row of the observation matrix used to make the forecast and collect the error. In all cases, the first column contains the dependent variable and other columns contains the regressors.

The regression matrix is also made using a custom function. It also use a custom function to compute MSE and model fitness for the GA. I use packages 'e1071' for the SVR and 'GA' for the genetic algorithm.

THE PROBLEM

Yesterday, everything was working fine. I actually managed to run the genetic algorithm, get optimal hp's and produce a forecast. Today, I added a function to create a proper matrix for the 'predict function' and managed to get a forecast using optimal hp's and those last observed values. I unfortunately did not save many copies of my work (which I will never do again), so I can't just get back the working code.

However, I might have changed a line somewhere along the way in one of my custom functions. The complexity of the problem is that 'ga' calls 'fit_fct', which calls 'mse_fct', which calls 'svm'... And if you run each of those functions alone, they work fine with the objects I use (i.e., fit_fct, mse_fct and all other functions work on their own. The problem is really with how 'ga' calls them).

I get this error message:

**' Error in svm.default(x, y, scale = scale, ..., na.action = na.action) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 12) '**

Now, I will provide you with codes to reproduce everything. First, all functions:

```
# TS_validation -------------------------------------------
TS_samples <- function(data, frac, h){
 # Description: this function forms training and test samples
 # in an extended window POOS pattern. 
 #
 # INPUTS
 # Data contains both left hand and right hand side variables
 # frac is the fraction used for testing the model
 # h is the forecast horizon
 # 
 # OUTPUTS
 # list_TS is a list containing both training and test sets
 # organized as follows: list_TS[[sample]][[type]] where
 # type==1 is the training set and type==2 is the test set.

  bigt <- nrow(data)             # Length of training set
  tau  <- round((1-frac)*bigt)   # Start of OOS

  list_TS <- lapply(tau:bigt, function(i) list(
       train <- data[1:(i-h),],
       test  <- data[i,]
       ))
   return(list_TS)
 } # ----------------------------------------------------- #
 # MSE function for SVM ------------------------------------
 mse_fct <- function(formula_svm, train, test, cost, gamma, nu){
 # Description: computes MSE for an nu-SVR using training
 # and test sets.
 # 
 # NOTE: variable to forecasted must be in the first column
 # Dependencies: e1071
 #
 # INPUTS
 # formula_svm is the structure of the model
 # train and test are training and test sets
 # cost, gamma and nu are the hyperparameters of the SVM
 # 
 # OUTPUTS
 # mse (mean squared error)

    test <- as.matrix(test)
 if (dim(test)[2] == 1){
    test <- t(test)
 }
 # TRAIN MODEL
 mdl <- svm(formula_svm, data=train, 
            kernel='radial', type='nu-regression',
            cost=cost, gamma=gamma, nu=nu)
 # PREDICT LABELS
 mse <- mean((predict(mdl, newdata=test) - test[,1])^2, na.rm=TRUE)
 return(mse)
 } # ----------------------------------------------------- #
 # Fitness function for GA ---------------------------------
 fit_fct <- function(x, list_data, formula_svm){
 # Nu-SVR parameters
    cost  <- x[1]
    gamma <- x[2]
    nu    <- x[3]

 # Get MSE across all folds
 a <- list_data
 mse_value <- sapply(1:length(a), 
                  function(i) mse_fct(formula_svm = formula_svm, 
                                      train=a[[i]][[1]], test=a[[i]][[2]],
                                      cost=cost, gamma=gamma, nu=nu))
 # Fitness measure is maximized, thus -mse
 fit <- -mean(mse_value)
 return(fit)
 } # ----------------------------------------------------- #
 # Function to make regression matrix ----------------------
 make_reg_matrix <- function(y,factors,h,max_y,max_f){
 # Description: This function creates a regression matrix
 # containing the dependent variable, y, its lagged values
 # from h to max_y and lagged exogenous regressors, 
 # from lag h to max_f
 #
 # NOTE: y and factors must of same time dimension.
 #
 # OUTPUT
 # First column is dependent variable. All others are
 # regressors. 

 if (max_y < h || max_f < h){
   stop('Lags must be greater than or equal to forecast horizons.')
 }

 bigt <- nrow(as.matrix(y))       # Time dimension
 bign <- ncol(as.matrix(factors)) # Number of factors

 lags <- sapply(h:max_y, function(i) c(array(NA,dim=i),y[1:(bigt-i)]))
 f <- do.call(cbind, lapply(h:max_f, function(i) 
                         rbind(array(NA,dim=c(i,bign)),
                               factors[1:(bigt-i),]))
           )
 reg <- cbind(y,lags,f)
 colnames(reg) <- 1:ncol(reg)

 return(reg)
 }
```

Now, here is code similar to the function I am writing. It's just simpler to track bugs this way, in my opinion, and it does produce exactly the same
problem, so if it gets solved here, it gets solve everywhere:

```
 set.seed(1234)
 y       <- as.matrix(rnorm(100))
 factors <- array(rnorm(200), dim=c(100,2))
 max_y <- 3
 max_f <- 3
 frac <- .3
 h <- 2

 # FORECASTING CODE

 # Range of hyperparameters
 min_theta <- c(abs(median(y)-3*sd(y)),  2^(-5), 0.1)
 max_theta <- c(abs(median(y)+3*sd(y)),  2^5, 0.7)

 # Make regressor matrix and last observed values
 train <- make_reg_matrix(y,factors,h,max_y,max_f)
 # Drop NAs (if any)
 drop <- max(sapply(seq_along(colnames(train)), 
                     function(i) sum(is.na(train[,i]))))
 train <- train[-c(1:drop),] # Dropping missing values
 # Add names to columns for formulas
 colnames(train) <- paste('V', colnames(train), sep='')

 # Make newdata for prediction (last observations)
 last  <- make_last(y,factors,h,max_y,max_f)

 # Make samples
 samples <- TS_samples(train,frac,h)

 # Genetic algorithm
 formula_svm <- as.formula(c('V1 ~ 1 +', 
                        paste(paste('V', 2:ncol(train), sep=''), 
                              collapse='+')))

 results <- ga(type = "real-valued", fitness = fit_fct, samples,
               formula_svm,
               names = c('Cost', 'Gamma', 'Nu'), 
               min = min_theta, max = max_theta,
               popSize = 50, maxiter = 10, maxFitness=-0.002, 
               seed = 1071)
```

You can try to call each function individually (mse_fct, fit_fct, etc.) and see that, indeed, they work on their own. It's just problematic when I call 'ga', which is curious since all it really does is pick hyperparameter vectors and call 'fit_fct' to valuate fitness...

I would be really satisfied if anyone came up with a solution because I have absolutely no idea what is going on. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Addtional details: when I run the debugging tool, I see that the value used for the Cost hyperparameter is 'NaN'...

Comment: I feel a bit stupid... The problem was min_theta[1] > max_theta[1], so the genetic algorithm, for the first generation, tried to pick 50 values between min_theta[1] and max_theta[1], which is an empty set... So, when fit_fct evaluated the SVR model, it tried to estimate a model with an empty value for cost, which obviously doesn't work... I'll leave this here in case someone makes a similar mistake.